# New pc and google maps app doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a new pc and i moved my project that uses the Google Maps API v2 from the old pc to this new one. I want to make the app go on both the PCs. Is this possible to do from the Google API Console? Can i know the right sequence of operations to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you install a new copy of the Android SDK on a fresh computer, it generates a set of signing keys. The Google Maps API depends on the keys you use to sign for access. You'll need to copy the debug.keystore file from the computer that works to the computer that doesn't.